# Uri.EscapeDataString() is converting / to %2F

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, url, uri

I am trying to convert strings to URI format, in order to use them in URLs that show some images in my page. I am using ASP.NET Core.

for this I have used System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode() I also tried Uri.EscapeDataString() .

Both methods return practically the same thing (I would not discuss the difference between them in this thread) , but my problem is that the methods are also converting the character "/" to "%2f" .

Here is a piece of code that I am using for that conversion :

```
        public string StringConvert()
    {
        string decoded= "Example/of/string"  ;
        string toShow = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encoded);   /*Uri.EscapeDataString(encoded); can also be used*/
        return toShow;
    }
```

I am calling the StringConvert method directly from the HTML view, and use it directly for the src of an img .
the image cannot be accessed because of the "%2f" in the address.
Might there be a way/workaround to bypass that ?

Comment: I don't understand: why is that not correct? A URI cannot have a / inside a query parameter, so it's correctly escaping it.

Answer (score 0):

Converting strings into URIs could be achieved with `new Uri(string)`. However, if you need validation first to make sure it won't blow up with a bad string then you can check out `Uri.TryCreate(string, UriKind, out Uri)`.

Last param would be your URI object or just the result from URI initialization from the first example.

[Uri.TryCreate MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.trycreate?view=net-6.0#system-uri-trycreate(system-string-system-urikind-system-uri@))

Comment: TryCreate does not convert special characters which are n the original string , like for example : "#" or "%" ...etc  , I would like to build a valid URL out from a string that might contain special characters that are not supported once the link is called by the browser .